# Replacing NULL and empty string within Select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column that can have either `NULL` or empty space (i.e. `''`) values.  I would like to replace both of those values with a valid value like `'UNKNOWN'`.  The various solutions I have found suggest modifying the value within the table itself.  However, this is not an option in this case in that the database is for a 3rd party application that is developed and/or patched very poorly (in reality I think my Rottweiler could have done a better job).  I am concerned that modifying the underlying data could cause the application to melt into a smoking hole.

I have attempted variations of the following commands:

```
COALESCE(Address.COUNTRY, 'United States') -- Won't replace empty string as it is not NULL
REPLACE(Address.COUNTRY, '', 'United States') -- Doesn't replace empty string
ISNULL(Address.COUNTRY, 'United States') -- Works for NULL but not empty string
```

I know I could use the `CASE` statement but am *hoping* there is a much more elegant/efficient solution.

You'll have to trust me when I say I have looked for a solution to my specific issue and have not found an answer.  If I have overlooked something, though, kindly show me the lighted path.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Address.COUNTRY,''), 'United States')
```

Comment: This seems to have done it.  Beer's on me.  However, I'm surprised that it does work in that my understanding is that the COALESCE function will grab the first non-null value.  In the statement I would expect it to return empty space as opposed to the text string???  But, bottom line, thanks for the solution.

Comment: There are two functions in this statement, one `NULLIF` which is converting empty string to null and then `coalesce` which checks for null

Comment: @rs.: Note: `nullif` doesn't convert empty string to null, It returns null if two arguments are same ;).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you want a view instead of altering actual table data.

```
Coalesce(NullIf(rtrim(Address.Country),''),'United States')
```

This will force your column to be null if it is actually an empty string (or blank string) and then the coalesce will have a null to work with.

Comment: Having both `ltrim` and `rtrim` seems useless? If it's empty (except spaces) it's empty from either side ;)

Comment: @WoLpH aye, very true. I removed one. ( I guess I just habitually write both)

Comment: Creating a view hadn't crossed my mind though it probably should have.  rs and your variation provided an adequate solution so no need for view.

Comment: +1 from me, I think this is the better solution since it covers more cases :)

Comment: I see 3 opening parentheses and 4 closing ones currently... assuming the first closing parenthesis is a dud.

Comment: @JoshuaPech First one was the dud. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way can be this: - recommended as using just one expression -

```
case when address.country <> '' then address.country
else 'United States'
end as country
```

> Note: Result of checking `null` by `<>` operator will return `false`.
>   And as documented: [*`NULLIF` is equivalent to a searched `CASE` expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql)
>   and [*`COALESCE` expression is a syntactic shortcut for the `CASE` expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql).
>   So, combination of those are using two time of `case` expression.

Answer (score 2):

For an example data in your table such as combinations of

`''`, `null` and as well as `actual value` than if you want to only `actual value` and **replace** to `''`  and `null` value by `#` symbol than execute this query

```
SELECT Column_Name = (CASE WHEN (Column_Name IS NULL OR Column_Name = '') THEN '#' ELSE Column_Name END) FROM Table_Name
```

and another way you can use it but this is little bit lengthy and instead of this you can also use `IsNull` function but here only i am mentioning `IIF` function

```
SELECT IIF(Column_Name IS NULL, '#', Column_Name) FROM Table_Name  
SELECT IIF(Column_Name  = '', '#', Column_Name) FROM Table_Name  
-- and syntax of this query
SELECT IIF(Column_Name IS NULL, 'True Value', 'False Value') FROM Table_Name
```