# SQL Server Query for checking for empty string and replacing with something else

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I have an integration type project where my select column often has this code:

```
select 
CASE MyColumn
    WHEN '' THEN '&' 
    ELSE MyColumn
END
```

Is there a simpler approach? Sort of like coalesce with nulls?
I'm finding the query really hard to read, etc.

Thanks

Comment: see 'accepted' answer below. I actually didn't need to preserve the null, and the main goal afterall, was to simplify the query so it would be easier to read without repeating 'MyColumn' so many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try something like this...

```
 COALESCE(NULLIF(MyColumn,''), '&')
```

Comment: This isn't functionally equivalent... the original implementation would preserve a `NULL` value, this replaces `NULL` with `'&'`.

Comment: well spotted, ops @Vishal and me exactly the same answer :)

Comment: I guess in this case, CASE statement should do the job.

Comment: Thanks - I actually didn't need to preserve the NULL, but if I did, one of the other answers would do the trick... though remember, the initial goal was to simplify the select compared to a case when structure, and I'm not sure if any of the other answers simplifies it. This one does.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), following would check null and empty string [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244808/replacing-null-and-empty-string-within-select-statement) -

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(MyColumn,''), '&')
```

Comment: This isn't functionally equivalent... the original implementation would preserve a `NULL` value, this replaces `NULL` with `'&'`.

Comment: That's true, don't see a way around the case then.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Michael Fredrickson's comment

```
NULLIF(COALESCE(NULLIF(COALESCE(MyColumn,'###'),''), '&'),'###')
```

Replace ### with anyvalue you know won't appear in the field. Not sure it's easier to read than the case statement though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and preserve nulls:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(MyColumn, ''), NULLIF(MyColumn + '&', ''), MyColumn)
```