# Combine 3 Column when one of the value is empty( not null) remove extra space

Tags: sql, trim, coalesce

Data

```
col1    col2    col3 
5121     w        river road 
5512     empty    pine road
```

query 1

```
Select LTRIM(ISNULL(Col1+' ','')+ ISNULL(col2+' ', '') + ISNULL(col3+' ','') as col4 from ...
```

query 2

```
Select LTRIM(COALESCE(Col1+' ','')+ COALESCE(col2+' ', '') + COALESCE(col3+' ','') as col4 from ...
```

for both results i get this values

```
5121 w river road ( this looks good ) 
5512  pine road ( i get extra space for col 2 )
```

Thank you

Comment: `empty` mean `null` or string with length 0 ?

Comment: ok then i have empty or null values not 0

Comment: Col1+" " is always going to return a space on an empty string and therefor NOT null

Comment: @ChrisCaviness `NULL + ''` is `NULL`

Comment: Again, NULLS or string with `length = 0`  or `''` and  What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I do want to have space when there is values for all 3 column but when the col 2 or any other columns value is null  or empty i don't want that extra space

Comment: He doesn't have NULL+''.  We don't know if the Col1 allows nulls or if empty means empty string.  The point is he has two possible returns for a condition test, and must use an IIF, not a simple ISNULL or COALESCE

Comment: SQL EXPRESSS 2012

Comment: i just checked all my data it looks like only col 2 has null or empty values col 1 and col 3 always has values

Comment: I think the problem is your `empty` mean string `length = 0` you can see [**HERE**](http://rextester.com/ZFOK4213) with null the query works ok, the problem is with `''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have three cases

- NULL
- Length = 0
- Length > 0

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MUX70196)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([col1] varchar(5), [col2] varchar(5), [col3] varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([col1], [col2], [col3])
VALUES
    ('5121', 'w', 'river road'),
    ('5512', null, 'pine road'),
    ('3333', '', 'death valley')
;

SELECT COALESCE(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN '' ELSE col1 + ' ' END, '')  + 
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 + ' ' END, '')  + 
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN '' ELSE col3 + ' ' END, '')        

FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

Original OP and Jhon version work OK with `NULL` and `length > 0` but fail with `length = 0`

[image]

Comment: You need a test for NULL

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Where? Looks like `COALESCE` handle that. Or show me a border case in the DEMO site.

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(col1,''), Col1 + ' ') +

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Again show me a case where my query fail. Looks like your solution also work, but is just different to mine. Maybe you can post as a different answer.

Comment: Empty string <> NULL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283978/sql-coalesce-with-empty-string   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244808/replacing-null-and-empty-string-within-select-statement

Comment: I read that answer, but still dont see why you need it? If `col1 is NULL`, the `ELSE  col1 + ' '` will return `NULL`, and `Coalesce` will return `''`

Comment: @ChrisCaviness As I say your is a different answer, but looks like do the same.

Comment: This was definitely an exercise that I learned something from.  The "we can't assume anything" approach was very helpful.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Yes, check what was the first comment. You cant start solve a question until the question is clear.

Comment: @Juan Thank you This worked. i thought the CIALESCE will replace the empty value. it was a good lesson learned to check for both condition. good practice in future.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **Concat()** if 2012+

As you can see with col2 ...  `null+' '` will result in a null, the good news is concat() represents nulls as `''`

```
Declare @YourTable table (col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('5121','w', 'river road'),
('5512','','pine road'),  
('1313',null,'mocking bird lane')

Select concat(nullif(col1,'')+' ',nullif(col2,'')+' ',nullif(col3,''))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
5121 w river road
5512 pine road           -- No Extra Space
1313 mocking bird lane   -- NULLs handled
```

Comment: I cannot alter the table it is customer's data. i'm doing this on view. all 3 columns are set to varchar (255)

Comment: @john the table variable (at)YourTable is just demonstrative.

Comment: Your answer only works based on the assumption that Col1 or Col2 accept nulls.  ''+' ' is NOT null, and since this is coming from a database not under users control, or perhaps even ability to see the definition, you cannot make assumptions

Comment: select concat (col1+ '  ', col2+ '  ', col3) as col4 FROM ...  still i get that extra space when there is no value for col2

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Fair enough.

Comment: Use something like IIF(LEN(ISNULL(Col1,'') = 0, '', Col1 + ' ')

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Another option is a simple replace as illustrate above

Comment: Not sure if your solution works *(at least not in the [fiddle](http://rextester.com/BJU15347))*. Looks like you need a `CONVERT` first because col1 is integer.

Comment: @JohnCappelleti down vote removed for updated answer.

Comment: Clearly I'm in over my head.

Comment: Nope, now you have to see it through to the end.  Add in the convert if necessary for integer and keep at it until the answer is right.  :D

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Valid point, but I don't know if it is an int yet.

Comment: Yes, I make integer because the sqlfiddle make it integer, but if OP query is running maybe is string. Otherwise would be asking a different error

Comment: I think the problem is your `empty` mean string `length = 0` you can see [**HERE**](http://rextester.com/ZFOK4213) with null the query works ok, the problem is with `''`

Comment: Concat will do an implicit conversion of all types to string.  So if col1 is int it will be cast as a string automagically.  You were good before, but I'm a belt and suspenders kind of guy, i'd do the cast as well just in case.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness IF col1 is an int and we are doing col1+' ' you would still need to convert or force another space

Comment: concat(concat(col1,' '), ...  or replace(concat(col1, ' ', col2, ' ', col3 ...)...) except we could end up with a leading space if col1 is empty

Comment: @ChrisCaviness valid but does the same thing

Comment: I think the real answer to the OP question is don't do this in the model, return the columns and do it in the view or you're going to end up with a very ugly sql statement with cases testing for all the possible conditions for each column.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness Agreed, but I'm ready to move on  :)   The idea was to introduce the concept of Concat() and how it handles the implicit conversions.  I did make the tactical error of assuming EMPTY meant NULL  ... Ruthless crowd... I dig that.

Comment: Thank you John this worked as well i never though of using Nullif.

Comment: @john Hope it helped.  Never seen such a "Mean-Girl" response ... It was fun for me :)